# Reference and change activity elements from another activity

Tags: android

I have two activities, the main one and another activity that acts as a settings place for the first one. I have for example a switch that wants to set a layout from the main activity to `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` or `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

My problem is that when I try to refer to `l5` (the name of layout in the main activity) it doesn't recognize it. I set it to public in the main activity, isn't that how it works ? If it's public it can be used in other activites.

This is just one example, I want to make more settings stuff in there, like set the alpha of a Navigation Drawer or change the font size of the `EditTexts` in the main activity.

So, how can i set an activity that can change stuff from another activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of sharing data between activities of same application in Android:

```
public class OptionsActivity extends Activity  {

SharedPreferences _settings;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.options);

    // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
    // All objects are from android.context.Context
    _settings = getSharedPreferences(STATIC_PROPERTY.PREFS_NAME, 0);

    Spinner spBackground = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.backgroundsThemeSelect);

    spBackground.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = _settings.edit();

            int backgroundID = 0;
            switch (pos){
                default:
                case 0:
                    backgroundID = R.drawable.grass;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    backgroundID = R.drawable.earth;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    backgroundID = R.drawable.water;
                    break;
            }
            editor.putInt("background", backgroundID);

            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();                
        }
    });
....
}
```

then on the activity or background code you want to consume this settings:

public class ConsumerViewextends View implements GameListener {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefsFile";

```
public ConsumerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            int backgroundID = settings.getInt("background", R.drawable.water);
            setBackgroundDrawable(_appResources.getDrawable(backgroundID));
            ....
}
    ....
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks,just now i was looking at some tutorials for shared preferences,heh.Thanks,your example helps me understand a little bit better how this works ! Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

No this is not how it works :)
In android, activities represent screens. They do have access to each other members directly. What you can do is pass "Itents" between screens (that carry whatever information you need) or have some sort of global storage (that both screens can access) and put that data there.
For more on activities got to: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: Took a look on the link you provided,still have no ideea how to do what i want,lol

Comment: =), when i have the time i will provide an example of such a thing you are looking for, proving we are talking about a configuration activity, am i right?